# Accessing SSRS log programmatically

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, adomd.net

We have several SSRS reports. We call the SSRS execution web-service's Render method and pass the name of the report and the parameters which we want to execute. This method(report) internally executes MDX query returns us the ByteArray which we convert into JSON and pass to another application. All this is working fine.

**Why are we following approach**: We already have around 100 reports and we just want to use its output instead of creating new application which will execute MDX query using ADOMD and return us data.

**Problem:** If there is any error/exception during execution, I want to access the stack trace and the logs. Is there any way to get this information while executing the report or after execution is over?

Comment: Did you try anything yet, run any experiments? It seems the [Render method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) has an `out` parameter which is a list of [Warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.warning.aspx) objects (which can also contain errors, apparently), which may help?

Comment: @Jeroen: I will check and get back. thank you

Comment: By doing this you can have report execution log:
 SELECT TOP 100 *
  FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog2]
  order by timestart desc

Comment: @Shawn: Thank you for reply. But this will not give us the details about the query which actually generated the error. So if 10 queries were executed around same time, by looking at log, i will not know which query actually generated the error.